# Nextjs env variable is always undefined

Tags: docker, environment-variables, next.js

My project setup is like this:

```
project-ci (only docker)
  nextjs
  backend
```

Staging and Production are the same so I pass in `docker-compose.yml` file of staging only this argument (both environments are built with these commands first `npm run build` and then `npm run start`)

```
args:
    NEXT_PUBLIC_URL: arbitrary_value
```

in `Dockerfile` of the nextjs put these commands

```
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_URL
```

so variable will then be accessible in nextjs with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL`.
So far if I try to `console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL)` in `index.js` the value is always `undefined`. Any ideas what is wrong, also checked the docs but the result was still `undefined`

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

Answer (score 12):

You can access `env` variables using public runtime config property:

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      NEXT_PUBLIC_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL,
    }
};
```

then:

```
import getConfig from "next/config";
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL);
```

If it doesn't work, make sure the env variables are created inside docker container

Answer (score 6):

While NextJs has many pros, this is the one con that I have found with it. Because of their feature, `Advanced Static Optimization`(https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) env vars are converted into their values at build time. This is not very well documented on their site, but after a lot of testing I figured out the solution.

So you have to tell your docker image that when it starts up to `npm run build` before `npm run start` It will consume the env vars currently in the docker image and optimize them into the build with the values you wanted.

Cheers.

Comment: do you have any dockerfile example for this? Strange there isn´t any good documentation for these scenarios over at the NextJS site.

Comment: @objectclass At the bottom of my docker file I have `CMD [ "yarn", "start:docker" ]` and in my package.json I have `"start:docker": "next build && next start"` which will instruct the docker image to build before starting.