# NextJS: [dot]env.local returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

In my application I have created an environment variables into .env.local file and fetching it through process.env.ENV_KEY into component. But it is not returnig the actual value and instead it returns undefined value.

```js
.env.local
API_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4200/api/"
```

In component I am getting the value as `process.env.API_ENDPOINT` but it returns as `undefined`

```js
App.js
function App(props) {
    const loginUser = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post(`${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/login`, data)
    .then((response) => {
      router.push('/')
    })
  } 
}
```

I have also tried to config into env.js file but that also not worked any how.

```js
exports.env = {
  API_ENDPOINT: process.env.API_ENDPOINT
}

And into component have imported as 
import {env} from './config.js'
function App(props) {
    const loginUser = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post(`${env.API_ENDPOINT}/login`, data)
    .then((response) => {
      router.push('/')
    })
  } 
}
```

Moreover, I have also tried to create a build and then run the project but then also it returns `undefined` value.

Reference that I checked

- [Nextjs env variable is always undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64309158/5624578)
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default all environment variables loaded through .env.local are
> only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be
> exposed to the browser.   In order to expose a variable to the browser
> you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` :

So change

```
API_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4200/api/"
```

To

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4200/api/"
```

And

```
axios.post(`${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/login`, data)
```

To

```
axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT }/login`, data)
```