# React not reading docker-compose environment variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to set environment variables for React during docker image build. After setting up docker compose, React returns `undefined` as a result of:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID);
```

I confirmed that the running container sees the environment variable:

```
» docker exec -it mszan-portfolio-prod /bin/sh
/app # echo $REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID
foo
```

---

## Commands

```
REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID=foo docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build
```

```
REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID=foo docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up
```

## Files

**docker-compose.production.yml**

```
services:
  react:
    container_name: mszan-portfolio-prod
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
      args:
        - REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID=${REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID}
    command: serve -s out -l 3000
    ports:
      - 4050:3000
```

**Dockerfile.production**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

ARG REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID

ENV REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID $REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID

COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install -g serve

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/

RUN npm run build
```

## Project structure

```
├── Dockerfile.production
├── docker-compose.production.yml
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── pages
├── public
├── src
└── yarn.lock
```

Comment: This issue was related to NextJS, not Docker. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309510/13273250) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your build command like this:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build --build-arg REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USERID=foo
```

Then you can simply run your services using:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up
```