# Environment variable with no value in Next JS v14^, how to resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, dockerfile, frontend

The environment variable has no value (undefined) but is being defined from .env

In the development environment (yarn dev) the environment variable is assigned the value, but in the docker file environment it is not as if the variable has no value.

.env

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API=url-api
```

ja tenteni assim tbm

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API="url-api"
```

And that's how I'm calling it (in `.tsx` components), I added checkers and it still gives `undefendend`. What am I doing wrong?

```
 const apiURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API
    console.log("NEXT_PUBLIC_API: ", apiURL)
    console.log("NEXT_PUBLIC_API: ", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API)

    if (!process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API) {
      console.error("no endpoit")
    } else {
      console.log("with endpoint")
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        ...
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN apk add --update nodejs npm 

# RUN npm install --global yarn

WORKDIR /front

COPY package.json /front/package.json

COPY tsconfig.json /front/tsconfig.json

COPY public/ /front/public

COPY src/ /front/src

RUN yarn && yarn build

CMD ["yarn","start"]
```

version:
Nextjs: 14.0.4
React: 18.2.0
typescript: 5.3.3

Comment: please post the complete Dockerfile.

Comment: I added the docker file

Comment: You do not copy the env file. It has to present during the build step in the dockerfile

Comment: The .env is not included in the project because it is in a repository with .gitignore

Comment: find a (perhaps temporary) solution to this error.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66261784/23138458